# How to retrieve the instance type of AWS EC2 programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Java service running on AWS EC2, I guess I could probably
use AWS SDK to retrieve the instance type of current node.

I am wondering is there any other way to achieve the same goal without using SDK (there are some reasons I don't want my package become dependent on AWS SDK).

For example, we could query `/proc` to know the OS type or CPU info on Linux, is there any similar way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance type is available in the [instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html).

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type
t3.small
```

Comment: It does not work. My instances do not return anything at this endpoint

Comment: also how are you supposed to know the IP address to query?